# Count repeated words in a column using R

Tags: r, text, analytics

I have a dataframe with column 'NAME' like this:

```
NAME                            
Cybermart co                                               
Hot burgers hot sandwiches                       
Landmark co
```

I want to add a new column to this dataframe depending on:
whether there is any word that gets repeated in the 'name' column. 
So the new column would be like this:

```
REPEATED_WORD  
No  
Yes  
No
```

Is there any way I can do this?

Comment: What did you try? Why did it not work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
vapply(strsplit(tolower(x), "\\s+"), anyDuplicated, 1L) > 0L
#[1] FALSE  TRUE FALSE
```

Answer (score 0):

We can split te 'NAME' column by white space (`\\s+`), loop over the output `list` and check whether the `length` of `unique` elements are the same as the `length` of each `list` element to get a logical `vector`.  Convert the logical vector to "Yes", "No" (if required)

```
df1$REPEATED_WORD <- c("No", "Yes")[sapply(strsplit(df1$NAME, '\\s+'), 
              function(x) length(unique(tolower(x)))!=length(x)) + 1L]
df1$REPEATED_WORD
#[1] "No"  "Yes" "No"
```

---

If we are using `regex`, we can capture non-white space elements (`(\\S+)`) and use regex lookarounds to check if there is any repeated word.

```
library(stringi)
stri_detect(tolower(df1$NAME), regex="(\\S+)(?=.*\\s+\\1\\s+)")
#[1] FALSE  TRUE FALSE
```

It is better to leave it as a logical vector instead of converting to "Yes/No".  If that is need just  add 1 to the logical vector (or using `ifelse`) and change the TRUE values to "Yes" and FALSE to "No" (as showed above)

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar solution to @akrun's 2nd one (pure regex).  I'm going to put it in case it's useful to future searchers:

```
NAME <-                           
c('Cybermart co',
'Hot burgers hot sandwiches',
'Landmark co'
)

grepl("(?i)\\b(\\w+)\\s+.*\\1\\b", NAME, perl=TRUE)
## [1] FALSE  TRUE FALSE
```